# how to randomly insert html inside of html string without causing invalid html

Tags: php, domdocument

I've written a content generator tool for a project im working to assist me batch importing fake content into text fields of a database.  It just assists making the site look populated.

I'm using an external class called lorem-php-sum to actually generate the strings that I am inserting.  Its incredibly simple really, it just inserts paragraphs of text wrapped in `<p>` tags (and a random number of them each time) and I then insert these strings into my chosen table within a big loop.

Now the thing is, I want to slightly advance what content is being randomly generated and to add some html list tags, horizontal line tags and other stuff.  I want my new html elements to be placed randomly within the paragraphs that I get returned from this paragraph generator class.

The problem is that whilst I can easily insert list tags into my big paragraph string at some random point, I fear sometimes it may insert my new html tags within the existing markup in a way that will break the html.

Does anyone have a trick for inserting html with some rules into another string?  I imagine that maybe the php domDocument class can assist with this but not sure now?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to incorporate some kind of state machine in your generator.

You can think of something like this:

Step1: Choose which element to render: a textnode, a paragraph, a list node.

When you pick a textnode you randomly generate some text and return to Step 1.

When you pick a paragraph you emit `<p>` and generate some text, emit `</p>` and return to Step 1.

In the case of a list node you can only make list elements `<li>`, so pick a random number of elements and fill them with same rules from Step 1.

--

You can also allow nesting. In `<li>` you can add `<strong>` and `<em>`, similar for `<p>`.

You can make it as crazy as you want I guess :)

Tweak a bit with the coefficients to get good results. Try to make a generator that produces random, but predictable output, total length might be a good thing to control on.

Comment: Hi Frits. Can this be achieved with domDocument do you think?

Comment: No, you don't need it. You're just generating strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could hierarchically loop through multidimensional arrays. No cell without a row, no row without a table, as such no li without a ul.

```
$tags = array("<table>%s</table>\n" , 
                array ("  <tr>%s</tr>\n" , 
                  array("    <td>%s</td>\n)),
              "<ul>%s</ul>\n",
                arrray ("  <li>%s</li>\n") //continue with more tags
        ); 
$tags_simple = array("%s", "<strong>%s</strong>", 
                     "<i>%s</i>", "<p>%s</p>\n", "%s</ br>\n"
                    ); //etc, "%s" for a none tag, add more if you like
```

Pick a ramdom from $tags, multiloop them, sprintf the random sentences and add random simple tags to them. It's a standalone possibility.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to work this out with other code samples and using domDocument.
I ended up making a function that explodes the string via paragraph tags and returns it as an array containing each paragraph as a separate item.

```
function splitTextByPara($string,$split_on="p"){
// Add alternative tags to split on with syntax: |//ul|//br 

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $domx->evaluate("//".$split_on);
$result = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result[] = $entry->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $entry );
}

// re-encode to utf8
$result = array_map("utf8_decode", $result);

return $result;
}
```